# How to pass a JSON object to EJS javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, callback

Need some help here, i am trying to pass a Json object as myVar to the below home.ejs file. How should i assign the value to the variable called data ?

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">CSI ID</th>
      <th scope="col">App Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Below throws the error -->
    <% var data = <%= myVar %>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
      <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
    </tr>    
  <% } %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Error Message

```
Could not find matching close tag for "<%".>
```

> app.js

Here "projects" outputs JSON Data

```
  app.get("/",function(req,resp) { 

    client.projects.getAll()
  .then(function(projects){
    console.log(projects); //buildList.build is an array of builds, from most recent to the count parameter
   myJsonData = projects;

  });
 resp.render('nav', {"page":"home.ejs","myVar":myJsonData});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) accept the view name to render and an optional parameter that is an object containing local variables for the view. that's mean if the second parameter is an object like this `{ name: "value"}` then you can access variable `name` from ejs view. your code should be:

**Route handler:**

```
app.get("/",function(req,resp) { 

    client.projects.getAll().then( function(projects) {

        // render response when you get projects populated
        resp.render('nav', { page: "home.ejs", data: projects });

    });

});
```

**View:**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">CSI ID</th>
        <th scope="col">App Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- get projects array from the data property -->
        <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
                <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
            </tr>    
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```